# Run war file on localhost without having tomcat installed

Tags: java, tomcat

Is there any way to run a war file on localhost without having the need to have tomcat installed on the machine? I have built a web application using gradle, spring and tomcat and I would like to be able to send the project as a war file to someone else and have them run it, even if they don't have tomcat installed.

Comment: https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot

Answer (score -1):

Make it a runnable jar which contains tomcat inside. And then start the application with:

```
java -jar myWebApplication.jar
```

https://www.baeldung.com/deployable-fat-jar-spring-boot

Comment: I was using the gradle tomcat pluging by bmuschko. Would this still work?

Comment: With Spring Boot this would be one parameter. Unfortunately I don't know the plugin by bmuschko.